# Orchard module for send emails to subscribers

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, email, orchardcms

Is there a module for orchard that can send emails to subscribers with contact list, delay email sending, etc?

Answer (score 3):

None that I know of, although there is a [module](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.NogginBox.MailChimp) for MailChimp mail service integration. You may want to try it out.

On the other hand, it would be very easy to write such module.